How do I pass my html element to Javascript?
I have a TextArea and a <span> in my ASP.NET MVC code:
<div>
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Note, 4, 20,
    new {
        id = "Note",
        name = "textareaNote",
        maxlength = "250",
        @class = "text-danger form-control",
        placeholder = "Enter note here - limited to 250 characters",
        onkeyup = "showRemaining(Note, remainingC, 250)"
    })
    <span id="remainingC"></span>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Note, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>

Whenever onkeyup fires, it has an error with the "remainingC" span:
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showRemaining(itemX, statusX, maxchar) {
        var len = itemX.value.length;
        if (maxchar < len) {
            return false;
        } else if (0 < len) {
            statusX.html('Remaining: ' + maxchar - len);
        } else {
            statusX.html('Remaining: ' + maxchar);
        }
    }
</script>

Every time I try typing into my textArea, I get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: statusX.html is not a function


I struggle with Javascript.
What do I need to do to get this working?

Are you sure it's not supposed to be statusX.html = "Something something";

@Pointy, lol No. My JavaScript is terrible. I'm copying examples I see online, and trying to adapt those.

@Pointy, I just tried it. That eliminates the error, but the HTML of the SPAN does not update. ???

oh OK, I think I see kind-of what's going on, at least more than a couple minutes ago. Instead of what I said, I bet it's supposed to be statusX.innerHTML = "Whatever";

The .html("Something") form is probably a reference to jQuery

@Pointy, who closed my question because it was a typo? It wasn't a typo. And do people on here downvote when they can't figure something out? A downvote is supposed to mean there was a lack of effort, but I clearly tried getting it to work on my own and explained my problem. What's the deal with this forum?

I can't say why others voted, but using the wrong name for a method or property is a very common example of why questions get closed. Those things are specific to the API that is involved, and there are zillions of APIs in this world. The correct names for functions and properties are usually documented, and a trip to the documentation is a part of preparing a good question.

I got it.
The ASP.NET HTML was fine:
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Note)
<div>
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Note, 4, 20,
    new
    {
        id = "Note",
        name = "textareaNote",
        maxlength = 250,
        @class = "text-danger form-control",
        placeholder = "Enter note here - limited to 250 characters",
        onkeyup = "showRemaining(Note, remainingC, 250)"
    })
    <span id="remainingC"></span>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Note, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>

Like Pointy pointed out, the issue was with mixing some jQuery syntax with JavaScript.
I wasn't able to get Pointy's innerHTML to work, but I was able to get textContent to work:
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showRemaining(itemX, statusX, maxchar) {
        var len = itemX.value.length;
        if (maxchar < len) {
            return false;
        } else {
            var number = 0;
            if (0 < len) {
                number = maxchar - len;
            } else {
                number = maxchar;
            }
            statusX.textContent = 'Remaining: ' + number;
        }
    }
</script>

Example with less code
<script>
    function showRemaining(itemX, statusX, maxchar) {
       const len = itemX.value.length;
        if (maxchar < len) {
            return false;
        } 
        statusX.textContent = 'Remaining: ' + (!!len ? maxchar - len : maxchar);
    }
</script>


with all modern browsers you can remove the type="text/javascript" as they all default to that now.

statusX.textContent = 'Remaining: '+(!!len?maxchar - len:maxchar); it can all be instead of else {             var number = 0;             if (0 < len) {                 number = maxchar - len;             } else {                 number = maxchar;             }             statusX.textContent = 'Remaining: ' + number;         }

@MarkSchultheiss - that is hard to read. If you want to add an answer, I would not downvote it. I think people get scared to answer because they think they will get downvoted for their efforts.

I don't care about votes really as the goal is just the best answers.  I cannot add an answer to a closed question..  I will edit yours to illustrate.
